# Piped dir within Foreach

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm writing a script to delete pdf files older than 6 months in folder with the 'Email' prefix.

However, my second dir command within my foreach never runs, its code is blocked.

```
$Now = Get-Date;
$DaysTillDelete = "180";
$LastWrite = $Now.AddDays(-$DaysTillDelete);
$TargetFolder = "C:\Test EMDATA\EMDATA\";
$BackupPath = "\\SHPFS02\IT\EmPower Old";
$EmailFolders = @();

if(-Not(Test-Path -path ($TargetFolder + "\OldFiles" ))) {
    mkdir -p ($TargetFolder +"\OldFiles");    
}
$Network = Test-Path $BackupPath
#New-PSDrive -Name O -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "$BackupPath"; #-Credential $cred

Write-Host "Running Script"
dir $TargetFolder | %{

    # Only delete files with the Email prefix
    $name = $_.Name;    
    if ($_.Name.Length -le 5) {return;}
    $id = $_.Name.SubString(0,5);            
    if ($id -eq "Email")
    {       
        Write-Host "Found slip folder"        
        $EmailFolders += $TargetFolder + $_;        
    }
}

ForEach ($folder in $EmailFolders)
{
    Write-Host $folder;
    dir -path $folder -include *.pdf | %{

        Write-Host "Checking" $name;
        # Only select files older than 6 months
        if( $_.LastWriteTime -le "$LastWrite")
        {
            $activeItem = Get-Item $TargetFolder + $_;
            #Move files into oldfiles
            Write-Host $TargetFolder
            move-item -path $activeItem -destination ($TargetFolder + "OldFiles\");            
            if ($Network)
            {                
                move-item -path $activeItem  -destination "O:\";
            }            
            Write-Host $_;            
            remove-item $activeItem;
            Write-Host "Deleting" + $name;
        }
    }
}
```

The script works till line 31 but doesn't continue on past line 32 and being a fairly beginner PS user I can't see why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only use `-include` with the `-recurse` parameter.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849800.aspx

> The Include parameter is effective only when the command includes the
>   Recurse parameter or the path leads to the contents of a directory,
>   such as C:\Windows*, where the wildcard character specifies the
>   contents of the C:\Windows directory.

What you want instead is the `-filter` parameter:

```
dir -path $folder -filter *.pdf
```